# Use PHP Array Parameters in MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, stored-procedures

I was wondering how to use array from php to be passed as parameter in MySQL Stored Procedure. I want to use something like this with array paremeters inside MySQL Stored Procedure. (Sorry for the very normal way):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dru`@`%` PROCEDURE `do_update_bill_penalty`(array
)
BEGIN
UPDATE `bill` SET
            `bill_status` = 'OVD',
            `bill_status_description` = 'OVERDUE',
            `penalty_code` = array['penalty_code'],
            `penalty_type` = array['penalty_type'],
            `penalty_rate` = array['penalty_rate'],
            `charge_per_day` = array['charge_per_day'],
            `penalty_charge` = array['total_charge'],
            `total_amount_due` = array['total_net_amount'],
            `bill_modifiedby` = array['use'],
            WHERE `bill_client` = array['client']
            AND  `bill_account_number` = array['accountnumber']
            AND `bill_reading_date` = array['job_date'];
END
```

As you can see I've inserted it the normal way but it wasn't doing anything good. Maybe there is some syntax or technique to use array in stored procedures.  I've seeing to use array as string but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: I believe you must choose a valid MySQL datatype when passing in parameters.

Comment: I would pass them as individual items, this makes the stored procedure more reusable from other places than always having to build a specific array.